# How to use linq where condition to filter many keys in a list?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-9.0

I have a class like this:

```
        class Student
        {
            public long Id { get; set; }
            public long RelatedId { get; set; }
        }
```

I have test below:

```
            var list = new List<Student>
            {
                new() { Id = 1, RelatedId = 1 },
                new() { Id = 1, RelatedId = 2 },
                new() { Id = 2, RelatedId = 1 },
                new() { Id = 2, RelatedId = 2 }
            };
            var query = new List<Student>
            {
                new() { Id = 1, RelatedId = 2 },
                new() { Id = 2, RelatedId = 1 },
            };
            var a= list.Where(x => query.Contains(x)).ToList();
            var b = list.Where(l => query.Contains(new Student { Id = l.Id, RelatedId = l.RelatedId })).ToList();
            var c = list.Where(l => query.Select(x=>x.Id).Contains(l.Id)
                                    &&query.Select(x=>x.RelatedId).Contains(l.RelatedId)).ToList();
```

I want the result of a,b,c equal to the "query" variable,but a,b is empty,c is count of 4.So how can i filter "list" use filter "query"?

ps:do not use ForEach to iter "query",just use linq.

Comment: Because `a` and `b` query are matching by reference, but not by value. So `a` and `b` list will be empty.

Comment: For your reference, Elements are compared to the specified value by using the default equality comparer. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @MongZhu With C#9, it is compilable: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cttOR5

Answer (score 1):

If you change the `Student` class into a `record` which uses value-based equality It should work as expected. Two instances with the same property values will be equal.

```
record Student
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long RelatedId { get; set; }
}
```